# Translucent Navigation Bar is a solid color

Tags: android, material-design

If I enable the translucent navigation bar with

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);

getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION);
```

Then the toolbar is behind the statusbar (the statusbar is supposed to be colored but the navbar is supposed to be translucent). However, if I go to the layout XML for this Activity, and put in `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`, the toolbar is correctly laid out, but the navbar is then a solid color.

Here is the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<me.ccrama.redditslide.Views.SidebarLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="?attr/activity_background">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/anchor"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"

            android:layout_gravity="top|right"
            android:layout_height="1dp" />

        <me.ccrama.redditslide.Views.ToggleSwipeViewPager
            android:id="@+id/content_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:minHeight="56dp"
                android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
                android:theme="@style/ActionBarCompat"
                android:title="@string/app_name" />

            <ViewStub
                android:id="@+id/stub_tabs"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inflatedId="@+id/sliding_tabs"
                android:layout="@layout/activity_overview_tabs" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    </FrameLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/drawerlistview"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="?attr/card_background"
        android:orientation="vertical" />

    <include
        layout="@layout/subinfo"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="end" />

</me.ccrama.redditslide.Views.SidebarLayout>
```

The same behavior (colored navbar) happens if I put the `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` inside the `FrameLayout` instead.

The first image below is when the toolbar layout is messed up, and the second phone is when the navbar isn't translucent.

[image]

[image]

Comment: getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

Comment: but what if I've colored the statusbar? I've already set it to be red.

Comment: What's your meaning?

Comment: If I set the statusbar color to be transparent--and I've already called `getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.RED);` won't making it `Color.TRANSPARENT` overwrite the color? In the screenshots I posted, I wanted to keep the statusbar colored and ONLY make the navbar translucent.

Comment: whats your minsdk?

Comment: @MML13 Jellybean. But I've done a check to make sure this is only applied to Lollipop and above. My test device is running 6.0.1

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm also fighting with that issue :-/

Comment: @PaulWoitaschek Sadly, no. I just gave up on that option. :|

Answer (score 1):

Use theme below as your activity theme：

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

And use getNavigationBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

WindowManager

```
            /**
     * Flag indicating that this Window is responsible for drawing the background for the
     * system bars. If set, the system bars are drawn with a transparent background and the
     * corresponding areas in this window are filled with the colors specified in
     * {@link Window#getStatusBarColor()} and {@link Window#getNavigationBarColor()}.
     */
    public static final int FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS = 0x80000000;


    /**
     * Window flag: request a translucent status bar with minimal system-provided
     * background protection.
     *
     * <p>This flag can be controlled in your theme through the
     * {@link android.R.attr#windowTranslucentStatus} attribute; this attribute
     * is automatically set for you in the standard translucent decor themes
     * such as
     * {@link android.R.style#Theme_Holo_NoActionBar_TranslucentDecor},
     * {@link android.R.style#Theme_Holo_Light_NoActionBar_TranslucentDecor},
     * {@link android.R.style#Theme_DeviceDefault_NoActionBar_TranslucentDecor}, and
     * {@link android.R.style#Theme_DeviceDefault_Light_NoActionBar_TranslucentDecor}.</p>
     *
     * <p>When this flag is enabled for a window, it automatically sets
     * the system UI visibility flags {@link View#SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE} and
     * {@link View#SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN}.</p>
     */
    public static final int FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS = 0x04000000;
```

Window

```
/**
 * Sets the color of the status bar to {@code color}.
 *
 * For this to take effect,
 * the window must be drawing the system bar backgrounds with
 * {@link android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams#FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS} and
 * {@link android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams#FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS} must not be set.
 *
 * If {@code color} is not opaque, consider setting
 * {@link android.view.View#SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE} and
 * {@link android.view.View#SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN}.
 * <p>
 * The transitionName for the view background will be "android:status:background".
 * </p>
 */
public abstract void setStatusBarColor(@ColorInt int color);
```

Comment: I'm sorry--what? You said "remove below"? Also, I don't want the statusbar to be transparent--ONLY the navbar.

Comment: I mean that you should remove code I list above.Please provide your code of theme.

Comment: I don't have any of that code anywhere. I posted all my relevant code for what I have to set the navbar translucent.

Comment: getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);Just remove this line.And WHat's theme  of your activity?

Comment: That doesn't fix it either. Theme is custom. I tried adding the "navigationTranslucent" but that never worked

Comment: Can you provide completed code about setStatusColor and the code of theme?

Comment: My flaut.I was mistaken mistaken about windowTranslucentStatus and windowIsTranslucent.You should remove windowTranslucentStatus  in theme.

Comment: I removed that already. As much as I appreciate the help, it just feels like you didn't even read my post. I don't care about the statusbar, only the navbar.

Comment: @Nxt3 it seems that you should use getNavigationBarColor if you add FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS .

Answer (score 0):

From [doc](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.4.html#UI)

> If you're creating a custom theme, set one of these themes as the
>   parent theme or include the windowTranslucentNavigation and
>   windowTranslucentStatus style properties in your theme.

So you can use below theme but for Api 19+:

values

```
<style name="Theme.DesignDemo" parent="Base.Theme.DesignDemo">
</style>

<style name="Base.Theme.DesignDemo" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">#673AB7</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#512DA8</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
</style>
```

values-21:

```
  <style name="Theme.DesignDemo" parent="Base.Theme.DesignDemo">
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: Would I still need to do the Java part to set translucency? I already had tried what you suggested and it didn't work.

Comment: I tried it on lolipop with no flag and it worked, i do not know what your problem is, give it a try.

Comment: I added all styles